# Can I embed a YouTube video?

Tags: support, asking-questions, user-interface, images

I'd like to link a YouTube video (from Numberphile) and pose a question about its content. Is it possible to embed the video into the question body?

Comment: [Requested](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33391/339790).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to embed the video. You can only link to it.

In principle, the SE platform would allow to embedded videos, but this feature is only enabled on selected sites, not including this one.

If you want to suggest that it is enabled on this site, you could post a feature request.

Comment: How would I post a feature request? Add the tag to the question?

Comment: Better ask a separate question, using that tag. You can link this one for context. This one should actually be tagged support; except if you actually want to discuss the merits of having this feature. In which case  the question should reflect this.

Comment: Someone posts a feature request. That request is downvoted into the Marianas Trench and eventually deleted. A couple of years later, someone wishes to request the same, searches around Meta and finds nothing. New request is posted, downvoted into the Marianas Trench and eventually deleted. Sort of pointless, isn't it? Why not add tag [tag:status-declined] to this question?